# How to run TV through HDMI and control by TV Remote?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I am thinking to find a ubuntu application that will run TV on my LED Monitor over HDMI and changes channels by TV Remote. Not just TV, also youtube channels, and podcasts too. I just saw an article [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-linux-internet-tv-station-automatic-content/), that made me think it's possible. If not, let me know how far I can go. Thanks.